# getting 403 caller does not have permissions for push notifications

Tags: google-classroom

I followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications?hl=en to receive push notifications on a GCloud PubSub topic. I have made sure that the right permissions are given to the topic and it exists.

When I try to register an authenticated user using `registrations.create` API with the following body:

```
{
  "feedType": "COURSE_WORK_CHANGES",
  "courseWorkChangesInfo": {
    "courseId": "..."
  }
}
```

I then get an error saying something along the lines of "HttpError 403 ... the caller does not have permissions"

I have made sure that the access token has the right scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.push-notifications`

Any ideas on why the `registrations.create` call fails? There were no `error_details` in the error object either.

Comment: Check the [acess errors](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors) page an see if something may still be disabled. Is this working for any authenticated user at all, or is it not working for anybody? Also, does the service account have permission to publish to the topic?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, thanks for the reply. All other APIs are working correctly except the registrations.create, so I assume it's not becauuse of ClassroomApiDisabled or ClassroomDisabled or ProjectPermissionDenied. The only reason I can think of is the current authenticated user does not have access to the requested feed. However, when I use the same authenticated user in the Google Classroom app, I can for sure receive notifications, so technically my user should have access to the feeds right?

Comment: Have you granted the service account permissions as per [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications?hl=en)?